# Using iOS constants (from UIApplication.h) in .plist

Tags: ios

I'm adding landscape support to an app that's portrait only at the moment but want to make it configurable so that the orientation will auto-rotate or can be locked to portrait or landscape.

My Preference Specifiers look like this:

```
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Orientation</string>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Auto Rotate</string>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <string>Portrait</string>
        </array>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
            <string>3</string>
        </array>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>bz-orientation</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
```

Instead of having magic numbers for preference values, I'd actually like to use the `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` values from `UIApplication.h` i.e.
`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`, `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` & `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, as far as I can tell. However, with some preprocessor abuse, you can hack together a constant-to-textual (or the other way around) map, and then use strings in your plist. This is what I mean:

```
#define ENTRY(constant) @#constant: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:constant]

NSDictionary *orientations = @{
    ENTRY(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll),
    ENTRY(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape),
    ENTRY(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)
};

#undef ENTRY
```

Then change the relevant snippet in your settings bundle plist to something like

```
<key>Values</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait</string>
</array>
```

And in order to retrieve the actual interface orientation mask:

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *maskAsString = [defs objectForKey:@"bz-orientation"];
NSNumber *maskAsNumber = [orientations objectForKey:maskAsString];

// Enum types are often just typedeffed to `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger`
UIInterfaceOrientationMask mask = [maskAsNumber integerValue];
```

Comment: Thanks that was the route I was contemplating but wanted to check there wasn't some other way (I know C but iOS / ObjC is a bit new to me)